# Getting the selected value from Dropdown list in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working my application with Laravel.
Please I created in my view a dropdownlist :

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Type', 'Type') }}
        {{ Form::select('Select_id', $profiles, Input::old('Select_id')) }}
     </div>
```

I want now to get the selected value after the user selects it from the list. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say you want to get the selected value after the user selects it, do you mean after saving the data to the database and then retrieving it in an edit form for example? Or do you want the value as the user selects it?

Comment: Thanks firstly for your quick answer, I want the value as the user selects it because I will save it my database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comment above, it's fairly straight forward to retrieve the value from the select. In the controller method that handles the route this form is posted to simply use:

```
$input = Input::get(); or $input = Input::all();
```

This will retrieve all input values as an array of key/value pairs, with the key being the name of your field/input. If you have set the names of the inputs to match the column names in your database, then you're good to go.

You can also just retrieve the select value on it's own using:

```
$selectId = Input::get('Select_id'); or $selectId = Input::only('Select_id');
```

If you wanted to get all input except for the 'Select_id' field, you can use:

```
$input = Input::except('Select_id');
```

Once you have your input, you can then use this to create a record in your database.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify that you want to keep those old inputs. you can do in two ways:

- `Input::flash();` within the controller
- call the view with `->withInput()`

you don't need to pass `Input::old('Select_id')` to the `Form::select`, since the Form classes take advantage of `Input::old` themselves and automatically select the right value.